# Calling other forms to index in Yii2 advanced

Tags: php, yii2-advanced-app

Good day! I would like to put the forms from contact-form to index page. But I do not know how. The following are the codes of the contact-form:

```
/*create.php*/

<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
$this->title = 'Create Contact Form';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => 'Contact Forms', 'url' =>
['index']];
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;?>
<div class="contact-form-create">
<h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
<?= $this->render('_form', ['model' => $model,]) ?>
</div>

/*_form.php*/

<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm; ?>

<div class="contact-form-form">
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'sender_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'sender_email')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'subject')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'content')->textarea(['rows' => 6]) ?>

<div class="form-group">
<?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update'
, ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : '
btn btn-primary']) ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

`<?= $this->render('_form', ['model' => $model,]) ?>`

try

`<?= \Yii::$app->view->render('@frontend/views/contact-form/_form', ['model'=> $model) ?>`

Comment: Hello! Thank you for replying. I tried to use the code you gave me but it did not work. Maybe my question was unclear. What I wanted to do is to put the forms of the contact-form to the main page which is in the views\site\index.php.

Comment: You want to print the contact-form inside the index, right? Then you shall clarify the view path of the contact-form too, so I can edit my answer with that path

Comment: You are correct. The view path of contact-form is frontend/views/contact-form. The contact-form folder contains the following php files: _form, _search, create, index, update and view.